# How to move a div using a slide effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, effects

This code switches the visibility of frm01

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#reg").click(function () {
        if ($("#frm01").is(":visible")) $("#frm01").hide("slide", {
            direction: "down"
        }, 1000);
        else $("#frm01").show("slide", {
            direction: "down"
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

But underlying div (div bellow frm01) is moved up/down momentarily, without slide effect.
I want to move it also using slide effect.

Comment: (jquery solution) use toggle in steadof  hide/show (maybe you need to use jquery ui for more effects)

Comment: I tried toggle but it writes frm01 from left to right, like typewriter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a separate div, why not simply add that div to the jquery selector as well?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#reg").click(function () {
        if ($("#frm01").is(":visible"))
            $("#frm01,#otherdiv").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
        else
            $("#frm01,#otherdiv").show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Or, if you just want to animate the movement of the div, use the jquery .animate() function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#reg").click(function () {
        if ($("#frm01").is(":visible")) {
            $("#frm01").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
            $("#otherdiv").animate({margin-top: "50px"}, 1000);
        } else {
            $("#frm01").show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
            $("#otherdiv").animate({margin-top: "100px"}, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

More on animating CSS changes [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: I don't want to show/hide #otherdiv. I want to push it up and down if frm01 is visible or not. So maybe change it's top margin slidely

Comment: Do you mean something like "if frm01 is visible, push it up. If frm01 is not visible, push it down"?

Comment: reverse - if frm01 is visible, push it down. If frm01 is not visible, push it up